# chain rule in differentiating a CDF

Tags: density-function, cumulative-distribution-function

This may be a very easy question but when a CDF is differentiated, it becomes a pdf:
$${\partial \over \partial z} F_Z(z) = f_Z(z)$$
But let's say I have a CDF of $F_Z(\sqrt{z})$. Is the pdf this:
$${\partial \over \partial z} F_Z(\sqrt{z}) = f_Z(\sqrt{z})$$
or this:
$${\partial \over \partial z} F_Z(\sqrt{z}) = f_Z(\sqrt{z}) \cdot {1 \over 2 \sqrt{z}} $$

Comment: The cdf is a function. You just follow the normal rules for differentiation!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot create a CDF simply by taking a known valid CDF $F_Z(z)$ and replacing  its argument $z$ by $\sqrt{z}$.  Remember that a CDF is a real-valued function defined for all values of its argument, and when you write $F_Z(\sqrt{z})$, you are not telling us what value your new alleged CDF has when the *argument* of your new CDF has value smaller than $0$.  Now, if $Z$ is a *nonnegative* random variable, then the function
$$G(z) = \begin{cases} F_Z(\sqrt{z}), & z \geq 0,\\0, & z < 0,\end{cases}\tag{1}$$ is indeed a valid CDF **of a different random variable** $Y$ (it happens to equal $Z^2$) and if $F_Z(z)$ happens to be an absolutely continuous function, then the derivative of $G(z)= F_Y(z)$ which is
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz}G(z) = g(z) = \begin{cases} f_Z(\sqrt{z})\frac{1}{2\sqrt{z}}, & z \geq 0,\\0, & z < 0,\end{cases}$$
is the pdf of this different random variable.